# Overwriting a Backbone Models Change Event

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, backbone-events

I think what I want to do is pretty simple I just don't know how to do it. I would like to fire my own event when one of my models attributes changes for the purpose of passing some data to the event handler (whether the change was an increase or decrease in value).

Basically I want my handler to do this in the view

```
handler: function(increased) {
   if(increased) {
      alert("the value increased")
   }
   else {
      alert("the value decreased")
   }
}

// ...

this.model.on("change:attr", this.handler, this);
```

Comment: hmmm maybe my question is not clear, I want to know how I can pass data to the `change:attr` handler, right now that event is being fired "automagically" by backbone, whenever I call `set()` on my model.

Comment: What data do you want to pass? You'll have access to the model already and you'll know which attribute has been changed.

Comment: I need to pass the nature of the change, so if the attr value increased vs decreased i want to know. I guess I can keep a cache of the old value and compare them, I don't think this is very clean...

Comment: Ah. That is easy. It's already there. See my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go: You basically listen for `change:myvar`. When a change occurs you use your model's `previous()` to get the old value. Depending on whether it increased or decreased you fire the appropriate event. You can listen to these events as shown in the `initialize()`.

```
(function($){

    window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this.on('change:myvar', this.onMyVarChange);
            this.on('increased:myvar', function () {                  
                console.log('Increased');                
            });
            this.on('decreased:myvar', function () {                  
                console.log('Decreased');                
            });
        },

        onMyVarChange: function () {
            if (this.get('myvar') > this.previous('myvar')) {
                this.trigger('increased:myvar');  
            } else {
                this.trigger('decreased:myvar');
            }
        }            
    });

    window.mymodel = new MyModel({myvar: 1});
    mymodel.set({myvar: 2});
    mymodel.set({myvar: 3});
    mymodel.set({myvar: 1});

})(jQuery);​
```

Running the above will print "Increased", "Increased", "Decreased" to your console.

Comment: Works pretty well, thanks for the heads up. For my case, I needed to detect the event in the view that has an attached model. So the event `change:attribute_name` got triggered even when the model gets attached to the view in addition to when the model value gets change from the DOM input. So I had to check if `this.model.get('attribute_name')` is `null` to avoid detecting the event triggered in view `initialize` method.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at `previousAttributes()`

You can then compare:

```
If(this.get(attr) > this.previousAttributes()[attr]){
    console.log('bigger');
} else {
    console.log('smaller');
}
```

If you use that in your `change` event handler you're all set. No need for a custom trigger or a ton of code.

EDIT

This is from my [Backbone.Validators](http://toddself.github.com/Backbone.Validator) project and how I obtain the list of all attributes which have changed during the validation step:

```
var get_changed_attributes = function(previous, current){
    var changedAttributes = [];
    _(current).each(function(val, key){
        if(!_(previous).has(key)){
            changedAttributes.push(key);
        } else if (!_.isEqual(val, previous[key])){
            changedAttributes.push(key);
        }
    });
    return changedAttributes;
};
```

This requires Underscore 1.3.1 because it's using `_.has`.  If you can't upgrade that's an easy thing to replace though.  In your case you'd passing `this.previousAttributes()` and `this.attributes`

Comment: this looks similar to what @ggozad came up with. I accepted his because I liked the idea of listening to `this.on('changed:attr'` and firing a custom event in the handler. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: @matthew Yup. That is the best way to do it. The idea for this one is that you can do it generically by comparing attributes which makes it easier to reuse if you need. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

What if you fire your own custom event after listening to the change event?

```
handler: function(increased) {
   this.model.trigger('my-custom-event', stuff, you, want);
},
myHandler: function(stuff, you, want){
    // Do it...
}
// ...
this.model.on("change:attr", this.handler, this);
this.model.on('my-custom-event, this.myHandler, this);
```