# Backbone Model listenTo self

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to do a listenTo binding in my model to itself and cannot get it to work. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this, "change:projectData", this.processData);
}

setProject: function(id) {
  //do async call and get someData variable
  this.set('projectData', someData);
}

processData: function(data) {
  debugger; //not triggering
}
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439531/overwriting-a-backbone-models-change-event, basically: try `this.on('change', ...)` instead of `listenTo`.

Comment: We're probably missing some key pieces here. It seems to work, even in a fetch callback http://jsfiddle.net/btks3/

Comment: Thre's nothing wrong with using "this.listenTo(this ...".  But there's something wrong in the code.  Please post what you're really trying to do cause above has some problems (i.e. missing commas, missing async call, what's id).  Here's a fiddle without async: http://jsfiddle.net/btks3/1/

Answer (score -2):

At the moment your view/Model listens only event called "change:projectData" (allthough [documentation suggests otherwise](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog). I can't make it work that way either), not the change-event itself. To make it listen that spesific event, you'll have to add `this.trigger("change:projectData");` to setProject-function.

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this, "change:projectData", this.processData);
}

setProject: function(id) {
  this.set('projectData', someData);
  this.trigger("change:projectData");
}

processData: function(data) {
  debugger; //not triggering
}
```

I strongly suggest that you use listenTo instead of any other jQuery's event listeners, for it makes easier and safer to unbind all eventlisteners at once. Just call `this.stopListening();` when you want to stop listening, and you should be safe from memoryleaks.

Comment: This is incorrect. When you set "projectData", "change:projectData" is automatically triggered by Backbone, so you wouldn't have to do it. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set.  Secondly, there's nobody talking about jQuery events.  Are you referring to "this.on()", because Backbone uses this nomenclature as well http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on

Comment: Yes, backbone does use "this.on()" invisibly, but because it provides a neat and simple (and safe) method (listenTo) to do exactly that job, why not use it? But you are correct on that "change:attr"-thing. My bad.

Comment: Using "on" basically is "this.listenTo(this..), but I think Jeremy didn't promote "this.listenTo(this...)" because it sounds weird: "I'm listening to myself waiting to tell myself something, then I will do something". =) But in the programming world, following the "listenTo" pattern is my preference, so i'm with you on that because it's just one function I need to know and I know what it does.

Answer (score -2):

You need to trigger the event `change:projectData`

So this code:

```
setProject: function(id) {
  //do async call and get someData variable
  this.set('projectData', someData);
}
```

Should be something like this:

```
setProject: function(id) {
   //do async call and get someData variable
   this.trigger('change:projectData', someData);
   //or Backbone.trigger(...)
}
```

Documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger

Comment: But `set` already triggers events: ["If any of the attributes change the model's state, a `"change"` event will be triggered on the model. Change events for specific attributes are also triggered, and you can bind to those as well, for example: `change:title`, and `change:content`."](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set).